# Uncommenting not working on Javascript file

Tags: comment, javascript

I am trying to use the block un-comment command `C-x C-;` but I am getting the error message "Can't find the comment end". I am writing Javascript code in an .html file. The block comment command works and correctly adds the `//`-type commands. Any recommendations? Is this a bug? Is there any other info that might be necessary to know?

Edit: The following code gives a simple example of what's going wrong:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Comment Test</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Here is some stuff<h1>
  </body>

  <script>
    // console.log("Hello World!");
  </script>
</html>
```

If I put my cursor at the end of the `console.log("Hello World!");` command and then type `C-x C-;` Emacs gives "Can't find the comment end". The `C-u M-x comment-region` command gives the same error, so I think it is already bound to that key set.

Edit 2: I am currently in version 27.1, and my init file only changes the theme. The major mode that I am in appears to switch to `mhtml-mode` when I am in the html portion of the document, and `js-mode` when I am in the Javascript portion of the document. When I switch to either `html-mode` or `javascript-mode` it comments and uncomments fine.

Comment: Can you show an example, and say where you put the cursor or define the region, etc.? IOW, make clear just what you're doing. 

Also, does `C-u M-x comment-region` do what you want? If it does, maybe bind `comment-region` to a key and use that.

Comment: @Drew Edited for clarification. Also what does IOW mean?

Comment: IOW = "in other words".

Comment: FWIW, `C-x C-;` works for me, starting with `emacs -Q` (no init file). It works with cursor at the beginning or end of that commented line. And it works in both `html-mode` and `javascript-mode` (different kinds of comment). What mode is your buffer in? What Emacs version? Did you use `emacs -Q`?

Comment: @Drew I am currently in version 27.1, my init file only changes the theme, and I am in `mthml-mode`. When I switch to either `html-mode` or `javascript-mode` it comments and uncomments fine. Not sure what `mhtml-mode` is, but it seems to do both html and javascript highlighting.

Comment: What's your major mode? Try `web-mode`.

Comment: @chen bin When I do `M-x web-mode` it says no match. When I type `C-h v major-mode` it tells me I am either in `mhtml-mode` or `js-mode` depending on whether I am in the html part or a script part of the code.

Comment: Please copy *all* relevant info to the question itself. Comments can be deleted at any time. The question should say that you're using `mhtml-mode` etc. Making the question complete and clear, saying exactly what you're doing, typically increases the quality of help people provide. It's hard to guess something like the behavior depends on `mhtml-mode`, for example.

Comment: Done, thanks for letting me know. Just to check: does this seem like a bug in the `mhtml-mode` that I should report?